# Помогите решить ошибку в idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

Я пишу консольную программу-тест на idle. Когда я его запускаю программа выдаёт ошибку: unexpected character after line continuation character. В чём проблема?
Код:

```
hello = print("Здравстуйте! Добро пожаловать на тест, который поможет вам определится с языком программирования. На вопросы нужно отвечать 'да' или 'нет'. Удачи в прохождении теста!")
q1 = input("Вопрос 1. Хотите много зарабатывать?" \n)
if q1 == "да": 
    print("Извините, но тест в разработке")
elif q1 == "нет": 
    print("Поздравляем! Ваш результат: Delphi")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас символ переноса строки за строку выскочил. Надо кавычки, которые перед ним, перенести после него:

Вот из этого

```
q1 = input("Вопрос 1. Хотите много зарабатывать?" \n)
                                               ^^^
```

сделать вот такое

```
q1 = input("Вопрос 1. Хотите много зарабатывать? \n")
                                                  ^^^
```